# Write a numpy.ndarray to an xlsx spreadsheet

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, xlsxwriter

I am trying to use xlsxwriter to write a numpy.ndarray to an excel spreadsheet.

The 'type' of my array is numpy.ndarray. The array itself when printed takes this form:

```
exampleArray = array([[[0.    ,  1], [0.    , 1], [0.    ,1]]])
```

The code that I am using is as follows:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('WorkBookName.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('workSheetName')

row = 0
col = 0

for data in exampleArray[0]:
    worksheet.write_colum(row, col data)
    col += 1

workbook.close()
```

I get the error:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tell'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you open to using Pandas?

Comment: What arguments does `write_colum` expect?  `data` in the loop (for a 2d array) will be a 1d array.

Comment: @jpp Yes. I'm open to anything that will just do what I want!

Comment: @hpaulj, it expects the row, the column and the actual data to be written to that row. If I were to print data, i.e. for data in exampleArray[0]: print(data), I get [0.    1] on successive lines

Comment: xlsxwriter and pandas: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

Comment: https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/12 - example using `write_row`.

Answer (score 5):

Using Pandas, this is straightforward. You just need to make sure the array is 2-dimensional.

```
import pandas as pd

A = np.array([[[0.    ,  1], [0.    , 1], [0.    ,1]]])

# construct dataframe, index [0] to make 2d
df = pd.DataFrame(A[0])

# save to Excel, exclude index and headers
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: it works nicely, many thanks! the only little problem that I have is that I get a 0 value in the first row of the generated xlsx file. Any idea of why this happens?.